# To become (a)... Usage of the indefinite article

Tags: indefinite-article

> His ambition is to become a musician.
>   She became queen in 1952.
>   How
>   to be governor

In what cases do we use the indefinite article in expressions with "be", "become" and when we don't?

Comment: Copular can take a bare role noun phrase as a complement. But it needs to have a special property so it can be considered a role. See [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/268282/can-predicative-complements-not-be-bare-noun-phrases-in-english-that-is-are-cl)

Answer (score 1):

It is context based.

If for instance, the conversation was about England and the queen, "she became queen" is correct because there is only one queen. "she became the queen" would also be acceptable.

"How to be governor" or "How to be the governor" would both be as acceptable as "How to be a governor", but it's based on the context of the conversation.

Basically, if you can add "the" before the noun and it's still make sense, then you don't need "a". "His ambition is to become the musician" would not make sense, therefore you use "a".